# Swift 4 UIActivityViewController send an Image with AirDrop

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a problem, I would like to sent an Image with E-Mail, Message and also AirDrop. Currently only E-Mail and Message works, when I try to sent it per AirDrop, the Device get an .data File, which I can't open. How I can fix this problem ?

```
@IBAction func sendItButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let imageShare = [ image! ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageShare , applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: Double check If `imageShare` is type of `UIImage` ?

Comment: I do not think I can solve the problem with it. The problem is, if I send it by e-mail, a Image will be sent, but if I try it with AirDrop I get a .data file

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue today, seems like there's a bug on UIActivityViewController if the UIImage is originated from a .jpeg image from bundle. I used the file URL of the image (instead of UIImage) as the activityItems and it worked fine.

```
private func urlForBundleFile(filename: String) -> URL? {
    let components = filename.components(separatedBy: ".")
    return Bundle.main.url(forResource: components[0], withExtension: components[1])
}

let imageURL = urlForBundleFile(filename: "someImage.jpeg")
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageURL] , applicationActivities: nil)
```